# Using Email instead of username in MVC 5 identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to use email not username in login method
here is my code

```
   var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
```

It is always use username,Find and FindAsync using username not Email

How can i use email in login?

Comment: Did you check that ?i checked and that is not duplicate

Comment: It's exactly a duplicate, actually, he wrote that answer

Comment: Check the method i have and the question have answer have.You only see it marked answer and say it is answer